# Get json file data which stored in Azure blob storage in React

Tags: json, reactjs, azure

I'm new to react and I am trying to get data from json file stored in Azure blob storage ([file](https://mcbstorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/exports/person.json)).

I have used following code to fetch the data but it is not success.

```
export function getJsonData<T = any>(url: string): Promise<T> {
return fetch(url, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
})
    .then(response => {
        return response.json();
    })
    .catch(error => {
        return Promise.reject(error);
    });}
```

I have passed url('https://mcbstorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/exports/person.json') when calling the function, but unable to get the response from service call

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? Network? Runtime?

Comment: @Camilo, I'm getting 'TypeError: Failed to fetch {stack: 'TypeError: Failed to fetch', message: 'Failed to fetch'}'. Question in my mind is the way I use to get json file from blob location using fetch is correct approach?. I have used fetch in my Api calls successfully.

Comment: @Camilo, in network tab I got this issue ![Valid XHTML](https://mcbstorageprod.blob.core.windows.net/exports/Cors%20issue.jpg).

Comment: 403 means forbidden. You are having CORS problem, I suggest looking into it.

Comment: @Camilo, Thank you for your help. I will follow your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable CORS for your Resource (which is under storage account) through Azure Portal itself and then try to access you blob. I ran into similar issue and this solved my problem.
[image: Azure CORS]